# Cannot Find libatomic.so.1

Tags: gcc, cmake, redhat, atomic

I'm trying to build snappy, but I end up getting the error

```
 error while loading shared libraries: libatomic.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When I go look in `/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/` I do find a file `libatomic.so`

Which has the contents

```
INPUT ( /usr/lib64/libatomic.so.1.2.0 )
```

then if I go looking in `/usr/lb64/` only these files exist

```
libatomic_ops_gpl.so.1
libatomic_ops_gpl.so.1.1.2
libatomic_ops.so.1
libatomic_ops.so.1.1.1
```

I try doing `yum install libatomic_ops.x86_64`, it says nothing to do. That is the only package that comes up when doing `yum search libatomic`.

I'm confused with how to solve this issue. Thanks!

For what it matters, this is a redhat 8.6 machine.

Comment: You should use `gcc -O2 -latomic` to let it pick the right version.

Comment: @PeterCordes It says that -02 is an unrecognized command line option

Comment: Then you're not using GCC or clang, which is weird for a question you tagged [gcc]...  But anyway, `-O2` is just to enable optimizations like normal (and potentially inline most of the atomic operations, except on 16-byte objects, so no libatomic functions are needed in the first place).  But if there are any 16-byte atomics needed on x86-64, the relevant part is `-latomic` to link that library.

Comment: @Alex it's letter O, not number zero. Maybe that's the issue.

Comment: @alagner Yea, didn't notice that thanks. I'm getting `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib64/libatomic.so.1.2.0`

Comment: Sounds like your system is broken if the underlying ELF shared object isn't where the `.so` ld script says it should be.  Maybe try reinstalling your GCC package or whatever package is supposed to provide `/usr/lib/libatomic.so`.  (It *should* be part of GCC, as it's used implicitly by the compiler to implement builtin functions like `__atomic_load_n` (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html), similar to libgcc helper functions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by running `dnf install gcc`, this updated gcc and allowed for `yum install libatomic` to work